'coroutine' object is not callable
I tried to check the user's permissions through the decorator, but an error was thrown
async def perm_check(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        update: telegram.Update = kwargs.get("update")
        if not update or not await has_permission(telegram_id=update.effective_user.id):
            await update.effective_chat.send_message(
                text="perms",
                reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
            )
            return

        await func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@database.perm_check
async def start_command(update: Update, _: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.effective_chat.send_message(
        text="auth message", reply_markup=await menu.main_menu()
    )

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\py\ FinancialReportBot\.venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_application.py", line 1148, in __create_task_callback
> return await coroutine  # type: ignore[misc]
> File "D:\py\ FinancialReportBot\.venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_handlers\basehandler.py", line 157, in handle_update
> return await self.callback(update, context)
> TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

I thought that the problem was in the python-telegram-bot library, I thought that it could not use a decorator on the function it forwards, so I created a duplicate function, but nothing changed

Try removing async from the decoration perm_check.
